# Dynamically align on center divs inside another div with dynamically changing height

Tags: css, html, alignment

I cant find solution to my problem, so I am asking you for help... I have 1 div which is changing its height depending on browser window height. Inside of this div is 5 another divs 4 per line, when I resize window size to smaller size divs fall down on line 2, 3, etc. That´s good, but these divs arent in the middle of the main div which is resized and that is what I looking for... Thank you

HTML:

```
<div id="main">

<!--Div1-->
<div class="mosaic-block fade">
</div>

<!--Div2-->
<div class="mosaic-block fade">
</div>

<!--Div3-->
<div class="mosaic-block fade">
</div>

<!--Div4-->
<div class="mosaic-block fade">
</div>

<!--Div5-->
<div class="mosaic-block fade">
</div>

</div> <!--main-->
```

CSS:

```
div#main {
border: #CCCCCC thin solid;
max width: 840px;
height:600px;
min-width: 210px;
border: #CCCCCC thin solid;
margin:0 auto;
max-width: 840px;
}

.mosaic-block {
margin-bottom:50px;
position: relative;
float:left;
margin:4px;
top:50px;

overflow:hidden;
width:200px;
height:200px;
background:#111 url(../img/progress.gif) no-repeat center center;
border:1px solid #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `float:left;` for .mosaic-block, you might want to try `display:inline-block;` and adding `text-align:center;` to your main. It's a bit dirty, but it works !

PS. you might want to remove that `max width: 840px;` , I doubt it's a valid declaration !

Comment: Jep :) it´s working, but I also have to add text-align:left; to .mosaic-block because of text in it... Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

Add in your CSS #Main

```
overflow:auto;
```